# HTML5: Get List of all Date Functions

Tags: javascript, html, date, prototype

Is there a way that I can have the list of all the functions related to Date constructor directly from the browser. Obviously, I can just check online but I'm kinda curious about how I can access them from the browser.

Ex: `Date.now()`, `(new Date()).toLocaleDateString()`,`(new Date()).toUTCString()`

Doesn't work:

`Date.prototype;`

`Object.keys(Date.prototype);`

`Object.keys(new Date());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date.prototype)
```

**EDIT:** The reason this works but `Object.keys(Date.prototype)` doesn't is that the properties on `Date.prototype` are marked as not enumerable (which means they also don't show up if you do a `for (var prop in Date.prototype)` either. On the other hand, [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) sees all properties, whether they are enumerable or not.

Comment: And `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date)` will show functions like Date.now(). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Most Developer Consoles have auto complete. Use it, and start by setting a variable: `var x = new Date()`. Then on your next command, just type `x.` and you should be able to see all the functions available on that browser.

The second way is be using the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date.prototype)` function to display the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in code if you are doing feature detection. And it will retrieve a list of them by name if done that way. GregL already shows a good approach to get the list. However, if you are looking for more information, such as which arguments are used in the methods or if this is purely informational, then the MDN (Mozilla Developer's Network) is ideal to see the exposed methods for the Date.prototype.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date